# Make Relation for every tables

Tags: postgresql, relation

Here are my tasks, I'm quite new to the field (Mysql/Postgresql) if there possible explain me easy much as possible

Create 4 tables

```
1. Chats
2. Messages
3. Files
4. Users
```

Create 3 users. 2 common users, 1 admin.

- Users can create chat and write the message and send files to the Admin user.
- Users should not see chats that they didn’t create.
- Users can attach files to message
- Admin should get all chats with joined messages and files
- Admin should get chats like this….

```
Chat 1
    Message 1
    Message 2
        File 1
    Message 3
        File 2
        File 3
    …
    Message n
Chat 2
    Message 5
    …
    Message m
    …
```

I want code to attach everything to each other

User to Chat, User have own id and chatId, Chat to Message, Chat should have own id and messages list where Chat may have much messageid [{},{}]  etc. Message... and File...

That all four таблес should cling, it is necessary to integrate the socket, but that I can myself, thanks who can and wants to help me

Comment: please post what you have tried.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. While there are plenty of people here happy to help you when you get stuck, you'll get better responses if you can show what you've done so far, and concentrate on one particular problem, rather than looking for someone to do all the work for you. If you haven't already, read through the [tour] and [help], and good luck. :)

Comment: I understand what is needed and how, but after the ORM Mongoos form I’ll confuse everything and I want to see at least one example of what makes the code so that when I put it on the editor it works without errors, that's motivational

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create tables like:

```
create table
    users ( user_id int primary key,
    user_name varchar(250),
    ischat boolean,    --do chat
    ismessage boolean, --do message
    isfiles boolean,   --do file
    isactive boolean,  --online user or not
    datecreated date )
create table
    chat ( id int primary key,
    somevalue varchar(200) ) 
create table
    message ( id int primary key,
    chat_id int references chat(id),
    somevalue varchar(200) )
create table
    file ( id int primary key,
    message_id int references message(id),
    somevalue varchar(200) )
```

Then, you manage your tables. If any question, please ask me?

Comment: it helps me a lot, thanks, but I want to continue a bit to have ready code, and then I’ll see everything in detail, so now, as it is written on the task, the admin should see and in my opinion if the admin do not have table but it should be able to many users, how can this be realized?

Comment: and why you only caught the file and the message doesn’t it’s necessary that the user had a chat_id and a chat had a messages_id [{messages_id: 45645}{messages_id: 82268}{messages_id: 456548}] for example?

Comment: First of all, you add a new column that like isadmin that can manage all users like 

`ALTER TABLE users
add column isadmin boolean`

I do not understand the second question, sorry.

Comment: thanks anyway, can you add the code where the admin sees the chat where he can see the message and in the message can see the files, in Mongoos this thing is called buy populate